# Printing a picture from a Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, image, printing, console-application

I am trying to find how to print a picture (as in on paper) in C#.  I'm trying to keep it very simple. So no use of WinForms and just using Console output.

I looked for an answer myself, but couldn't make sense of any of the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You necessarily don't need a WinForm application to do printing. JUst use [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx) and [DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b829w21x.aspx) class and you can do somthing like this:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (thesender, ev) => {
        ev.Graphics.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("Your Image Path"), 
        //This is to keep image in margins of the Page.
        new PointF(ev.MarginBounds.Left,ev.MarginBounds.Top));
    };
pd.Print();
```

Hope that Helps. (I have used Lambada and Anonymous Delegate to handle the Event, I f you dont understand that please tell i will post the normal version)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as simple as sending the byte stream of the picture to a C# printing library? just like how you would print any other document, like a PDF say, which is actually a collection of images. And the settings of say alignment, layout, B/W or color will then be printer-specific.